# I want to show/hide content with tabs AND change fullscreen background at the same time. Is this even possible?

Tags: jquery, background

I'm working with a client who wants a site with a full-screen background that changes when a show/hide tab is clicked.

I consider myself pretty good at adapting jquery, but i'm stumped.  I don't really have any code to show, but if anyone can at least point me in the right direction I can probably figure it out.

thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HzWRT/